# What is a good practice for connecting several parts of a project written in different programming languages?

Tags: programming-practices, programming-languages, performance

Usually passing data inside a project isn't a big problem as long as everything is written in one language. However things may turn ugly, if parts of the program are written in different languages. For example: A java method suddenly needs to call a method written in python or vice versa. This is of course manageable, however I believe the consensus is: A programmer should avoid those situations and keep these kinds of interactions to a minimum.

I do wonder now though: How are those situations handled best - especially in regards of performance and error handling.

For simplicity: One may assume the project is intended to analyze data files locally stored as .xlsx, .xml., .txt etc. that are read and written to. Bonus: These parts of the project may use multi threading and the steps of the analysis may also be depending on another.

I can imagine several different approaches:

For example should I use some kind of script/code interpreter and simply pass it every time the demanded file and let the interpreter execute a certain method?

Should I let the code execute a command via the command line including arguments?

Should I write everything to a config file (or multiple), that are continuously read by the different program parts?

How can I make sure that the different programs parts do not interfere with another?

EDIT: I found helpful: [How do multiple-languages interact in one project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636841/how-do-multiple-languages-interact-in-one-project)

Related: [How does code written in one language get called from another language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840888/how-does-code-written-in-one-language-get-called-from-another-language?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Did the linked threads answer your question?

Comment: As stated, I think the question is far to broad, since it could cover everything from network protocols and distributed architecture to C calling conventions or embedded scripting engines. But if you can narrow the issue down it might be possible to help.

Comment: I specified the kind of project I am mainly interested in for the moment - I hope it is good/useful enough.

Comment: There is no "best" for such situations. I can not only imagine several different approaches, but had to deal with several different approaches for this in reality. From that I can tell you: this is not a good question for a hypothetical case. It is better to ask this for a real situation, each real case is different and might require different measures.

Comment: @DocBrown, ah ok, I will consider doing so. I hoped there were one good way, that applied to most cases. I do wonder so, given a real case how does one find the right measures? Regarding my question above: I find the balance very difficult now between making it as general as possible so that answers help me and preferable help as many people as possible in the future, but still precise enough that answers actually solve the issues. 
Of course I could ask a question a day, but this does not sound efficient..

Comment: Application Program Interface

Comment: The best practice is to avoid this situation.

Comment: I'd suggest you take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_WebSphere_MQ Then decide for yourself whether or not it's a good fit for your requirements. It's got a whole variety of api's.

Comment: This was tough enough in the old days with a different client and server language never mind the plethora of layers and languages we have now. I'd try to avoid the quagmire of calling different layers directly. In fact, these days I've noticed more and more systems being implemented via microservices with a language agnostic messaging platform such as RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 2):

If all of the programs are running at the same time, you could have an event loop in all of the programs listening to file changes.

For example, let's say you have an address book program. The Java part is used for managing the collection, but the python part looks up the first and last name based on user id.

You might have a `.raw` file as the first step. The Java program is monitoring the folder and notices `.raw` file has been created. The Java program changes the name to `.processing`, works on it, determines it needs the first and last name, renames the file to `.needs.names`, the python program is monitoring for files ending in `.needs.names`, fetches the names from somewhere, modified the file, and then renames it to `.ready` for the next program to pick it up.